# Making Python package data available outside the package's code

Tags: python, setuptools

I am creating a python package that needs to include a set of tools I have written along with some data files (csv and xlsx files).  The data files need to be accessible from my python code (which I've got working just fine via pkg_resources), but they also need to be accessible by other applications.

This means that, after installation, they need to live in directory whose path other applications can access.  I have this in my setup.py:

```
      package_data={
      "" : ["*.rst"],
      "Koala" : ["*.csv",
                 "*.xlsx"
             ]
       },
```

If I run

```
python setup.py sdist
```

the csv and xlsx files end up in the resulting egg.  However, installing the package doesn't seem to unpack the egg, so the files are only visible via pkg_resources.

How can I ensure that the files in my package will be available outside of my packge?

Comment: When you install the project with a `pip` then `data_files` are installed in system. I'm not sure why.